# wampserver - my website doesn't updating

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm using wampserver with my test website, but there's a problem. I have been trying to update the website, but the new content doesn't seem to show up. I think I should turn off cookies or something. I've tried to find a solution using google, but unluckily, I couldn't find anything. I had tried this code in the  section, but it doesn't help.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="expires" CONTENT="0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

Could anyone help me? Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried restarting WAMP?

Comment: Try hitting `CTRL + F5`

Comment: we might need some more details about your website. for all we know, you might be saving on the wrong file for example. you should also try  your website in a private window , as those windows don't use the cache.

Comment: If you are using Google Chrome open the page in Incognito Window. And if the problem continues there, you need to bother.

Comment: You will need to give us more information including code. Meta tags have nothing to do with this. Plus, why was this tagged as `php` `javascript` `css`? Show relevant code or edit accordingly.

Comment: did you confirm that you're uploading the new content to the right spot? all the browser/code fiddling in the world won't help if you're not uploading it to the right spot to begin with.

Comment: thank you for everybody :) The incognite window works :)